# Упростите код, чтобы уложилось по времени

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ограничение по времени 1 секунда

не проходит большинство тестов , т.к. выполняется дольше(входные данные и за какое время проходит эти тесты не дано)

```
n, k, s = int(input()), [list(map(lambda x: int(x) - 1, input().split()))[1:] for _ in range(7)], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
for _ in range(n - 1):
 s = [sum([s[i] for i in r]) for r in k]
print(sum(s) % 1000000007)
```

Comment: Вы обратили внимание на верхнюю границу `N`? При таких значениях без быстрого возведения в степень не обойтись.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Я не вижу, как радикально ускорить работу программы. Можно уменьшить кол-во вложенных циклов, но сомневаюсь, что это сильно поможет

Comment: А вы знаете что такое "быстрое возведение в степень"?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy нет, можете объяснить

Comment: [Алгоритмы быстрого возведения в степень](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`N` очень велико. Любой цикл по `N` не пройдёт по времени. Надо искать другие подходы. Рассмотрим общую задачу. Пусть мы знаем количество песен длины `n`, начинающихся с разных нот. Как вычислить количество песен длины `n + 1`? Связь между ними можно выразить как умножение вектора на матрицу `v(n + 1) = M * v(n)`.

Для примера в задаче матрица будет выглядеть так:

> ```
>     / 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 \  # 1 2
>     | 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 |  # 2 3 1
>     | 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 |  # 1 2
> M = | 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 |  # 1 3
>     | 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 |  # 2 4 5
>     | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |  # 0
>     \ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 /  # 0
> ```

Число песен длины один, два и три:

> ```
>      / 1 \                  / 1 \                  / 2 \
>      | 1 |                  | 2 |                  | 2 |
>      | 1 |                  | 1 |                  | 2 |
> v1 = | 1 |    v2 = M * v1 = | 1 |    v3 = M * v2 = | 1 |
>      | 1 |                  | 2 |                  | 3 |
>      | 1 |                  | 0 |                  | 0 |
>      \ 1 /                  \ 0 /                  \ 0 /
> ```

Матричное произведение ассоциативно. Поэтому число песен длины `N` будет равно `vN = M^(N-1) * v1`.

Задача сведена к возведению матрицы в степень. Используем [быстрое возведение в степень](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C). Это позволит получить степень матрицы за логарифмическое число умножений.

Дополнительно заметим что ответ нам нужен по модулю. Везде в призведениях матриц результат возьмем по модулю. Это ограничит длину целых которые умножаются и ещё ускорит решение, и значительно.

Когда степень матрицы получена её надо умножить на `v1` и сложить все числа результата. Получившаяся сумма оказывается равна сумме всех элементов матрицы.

Всё вместе:

```
def read_line():
    tokens = input().split()[1:]
    notes = [0] * 7
    for i in (int(t) - 1 for t in tokens):
        notes[i] = 1
    return tuple(notes)

def mul(a, b):
    return tuple(
        tuple(
            sum(a[i][k] * b[k][j] for k in range(7)) % 1000000007
            for j in range(7)
        )
        for i in range(7)
    )

unit = tuple(
    tuple(
        1 if i == j else 0
        for j in range(7)
    )
    for i in range(7)
)

def pow(a, n):
    if n == 0:
        return unit
    if n == 1:
        return a
    if n % 2 == 0:
        p2 = pow(a, n // 2)
        return mul(p2, p2)
    return mul(a, pow(a, n - 1))

n = int(input())
m = tuple(read_line() for _ in range(7))
p = pow(m, n - 1)
print(sum(map(sum, p)) % 1000000007)
```